# Copy of ID card: blacken / hide fields that are not relevant (Switzerland)

Tags: privacy, gdpr, switzerland

In recent c't there is an article about GDPR (Sorry for the German). In Switzerland there is so far no GDPR, but we have a similar mechanism [called Auskunftsrecht](https://www.edoeb.admin.ch/edoeb/de/home/datenschutz/ueberblick/das-auskunftsrecht.html).
[image]

In article there is written that customer can blacken / hide fields that are not relevant from ID card. Does this also apply to Switzerland? In the past when requesting data about me, I attached full copy of ID card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under GDPR the principle of Data Minimization rules that companies should not keep Personal Data that is irrelevant towards the fulfillment of a given service they render you.
So, YES, you can "hide"/ cover" Data on any document that goes beyond what is "vital" to ensure the Service is rendered.

Let's imagine I am to become a member of a Library, I can blur on my ID Card everything but Address; name; Fiscal number and photo... all the rest is irrelevant for the Library to grant me a membership and would mean they would have Personal Data about me without a Lawful Base, while raising my personal risk in case of a Data Breach.